# Using Pi to check mipi clk?

Tags: camera, raspicam, driver

I'm using the Pi 4 compute module to connect to a IMX219 camera using the mipi interface. Well, actually putting the mipi through a FPGA interface first but the basic question is:

Can I use the Pi to check if the differential mipi clk is running?

I need to check if the FPGA output is working. I can otherwise interface with the camera but e.g. raspistill won't take a picture, timing out with the "no data received" error.

**Update:**
So I implemented a CSI bridge on the FPGA (Lattice Crosslink) and confirmed via oscilloscope that there are high speed CSI2 signals and clock being output by the FPGA. But I'm still getting the `Camera control callback  cmd=0x4f525245mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board` error. I checked the Pi and Camera on a different board and they both work just fine (i.e. can take pictures with raspistill).

So is there any way to check if a CSI clk is received? Or if any data is received, just not valid MIPI data?

Comment: progrsm the FPGA to not output differential MIPI clock ... do you get a different error message?

Comment: No, same message. But the clock is definitely not running. Turns out the PLL lock signal is just for the slow clk, not the HS MIPI clk.